# Why do NBA teams wear spanish jerseys?

Tags: nba, uniform

Several times, I have seen several NBA teams wear jerseys that say, "Los Lakers," "El Heat," and "Los Spurs" for example.

[image: El Heat vs. Los Spurs]

**What is the motivation behind why NBA teams wear spanish jerseys?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Noche Latina, established during the 2006-2007 season, is a program by the NBA to celebrate Latin heritage for fans and players in Hispanic and Latin American communities.

Each season, [selected NBA games](http://www.nba.com/2012/news/02/29/noche-latina-2012/index.html) contains Latin-themed activities, advertisements, and merchandise among other things in honor of "Noche Latina."

Teams who play in "selected NBA games" wear Spanish jerseys as part of the "Noche Latina" program.